# Multiple selectors not working in jQuery click event. I've used merge(). It works for first two selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Multiple selectors not working in jquery click event. I've used .merge(). It works for first two selectors.

```
var navLink = $("#carbonNavbar ul li a[href^='#']");
var sideIco = $("#sideIcons a[href^='#']");
var infoTag = $("a.scrl[href^='#']");

$.merge(infoTag, navLink, sideIco).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var hash = this.hash;

    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 1000, function(){

       // when done, add hash to url
       // (default click behaviour)
       window.location.hash = hash;
     });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`$.merge()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/) method is using for array merging, for combining jQuery objects use [`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) method.

```
infoTag.add(navLink).add(sideIco).on('click', ....
```

---

Or use [multiple selectors with comma separated](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
$("#carbonNavbar ul li a[href^='#'],#sideIcons a[href^='#'],.scrl[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {
```

Comment: I've tried with comma separated at first. It wasn't working.
I solved the issue by adding the same class in HTML. It is not accurate but it is working.
Anyway, Thank you very much. I'll try the add() method.

Answer (score 0):

['merge()'](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/) is for combining two arrays. You'd need to do another merge to add the third array to the combination of first two.